# Undefined reference compiling program with library "jrtplib"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, g++, shared-libraries

Compiling the following program

```
#include "jrtplib3/rtpsession.h"
#include "jrtplib3/rtpudpv4transmitter.h"
#include "jrtplib3/rtpipv4address.h"
#include "jrtplib3/rtpsessionparams.h"
#include "jrtplib3/rtperrors.h"
#include "jrtplib3/rtplibraryversion.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace jrtplib;

void checkerror(int rtperr)
{
    if (rtperr < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << RTPGetErrorString(rtperr) << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
    }
}

int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
g++ -o ex1 ex1.cpp
```

throws me the following error:

```
/tmp/ccDU6m7Y.o: In function `checkerror(int)':
ex1.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `jrtplib::RTPGetErrorString[abi:cxx11](int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

even though my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to `/usr/local/lib` and the folder contains the necessary libraries:

```
libjrtp.a
libjrtp.so
libjrtp.so.3.11.1
```

I compiled `jthread` as well as `jrtplib` with

```
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake ..
sudo all make
```

I also figured out that the examples from the `jrtplib` compiled successfully. My code example is a snippet from example1. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out where the difference lies. 
I think the answer to my problem is quite simple.

Comment: You need to *link* with the actual *library*.

Comment: You forgot to add `-l` to your command, `g++ -o ex1 -llibjrtp ex1.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @dasblinkenlight pointed me to the right direction. The following command did the trick for me in the end: `g++ -o ex1 ex1.cpp -rdynamic /usr/local/lib/libjrtp.a -L /usr/local/lib/ -ljthread -lpthread`